# How to limit the output of product tags on single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, tags

I would like to limit WooCommerce product tags showing to a certain number of words.

(let say to 5 words max).

I just want to hide other keywords with something like - "...", or "...see more", or "...see all".

This should also be clickable like a 'read more' button

---

I did more or less the same trick with Woocommerce product headers but can't find a similar solution for tags.

I used this CSS below which adds three dots at the end of a product name.

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could apply:

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/single-product/meta.php
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`.

**Replace:** line [36](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/single-product/meta.php#L36)

```php
<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

**With**

```php
<?php
// Set taxonmy
$taxonomy = 'product_tag';

// Get the terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );

// Error or empty
if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    return $terms;
}

if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
    return false;
}

// Set below number
$below = 5;

// Start
echo '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag: ', 'Tags: ', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' );

// Total
$total = count( $terms );

// Loop trough
foreach ( $terms as $index => $term ) {     
    $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
        return $link;
    }

    // Add comma (if not the last tag)
    if ( $index == ( $total - 1 )  ) {
        $add_comma = '';            
    } else {            
        $add_comma = ', ';          
    }

    // Below
    if ( $index < $below ) {
        // Output tag + url
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>' . $add_comma;
    } else {
        // Add 'read more' span
        if ( $index == $below ) {
            echo '<span class="tag-see-more">';             
        }

        // Output tag + url
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>' . $add_comma;

        // Close 'read more' span
        if ( $index == ( $total - 1 ) ) {
            echo '</span>';
            echo '<span class="tag-see-more-button" style="cursor: pointer;">see all</span>';               
        }
    }
}

// Close
echo '</span>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $( '.tag-see-more' ).hide();

        $( '.tag-see-more-button' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).hide();
            $( '.tag-see-more' ).show();
        });

    });
</script>
```

---

> CSS (styling) and further jQuery adjustments are theme dependent

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked great! But, there is no possibility to see the other keywords. I mean these three dots, in the end, are no clickable:-) Maybe my explanation was not that clear:-) Could you please give an idea how to do it? Like - "...see all"

Comment: Answer updated, know that further CSS and jQuery adjustments may be desirable depending on your theme and your desires. Regards

Comment: It's almost perfect! The only thing I would like to add is - when all the tags are viewing, there is no possibility to roll up them back, like - "...see less".

Comment: You can always ask a new question if you can't figure it out referring to this question. However, please show what you have tried in the meantime, otherwise your new question will be closed. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)